# Remove space before section and subsection only in the appendix

Tags: ieeetran, appendix

I would like to gain space only in the appendix by:

- Removing the new line when creating sections
- Removing vertical spaces before and after the subsections and subsubsections

While keeping the rest of the document the same. Is there a way to only modify the appendix and keep the rest of the document the same?

Here is the input:

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\begin{appendices}

\section{Why it's a new line}
Text is too separated
\subsection{This subsection is too much separated}
Also this is too separated

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image: Too much spacing in latex appendix]

Best

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You can redefine locally sections, but should you? If you are required to use the `IEEEtran` class, you  just shouldn't change the default format.

Comment: I've added the `\begin{document}…\end{document}` to make the example working. Please, always try to show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), which you've tested and which can be used to reproduce the problem and shown output without need to change anything. It is not good, if helpers first have to guess, what is missing, even if it would be just the `document` environment.

Comment: Maybe you want `ieeeconf` instead of `ieeetran` and `appendix` instead of `appendices`? But it would not remove the vertical space.

Comment: I must use IEEEtran, but some slack is allowed for the appendix, and I need to fit a graph in the page limit. I am trying to redefine locally the space and style of sections and subsections in the appendix with no luck.

Comment: Do you really need subsections in your appendix?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but this is as large a figure as I could fit on the same page as a section.

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\begin{appendices}

\section{}\vspace{-2\intextsep}
\hrule height0pt
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\rule{\linewidth}{\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal}
\end{figure}

\noindent More text.

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```